# DataFrame.astype() errors parameter

Tags: python, pandas

`astype` raises an `ValueError` when using `dict of columns`.

I am trying to convert the type of sparse column in a big DF (from float to int). My problem is with the `NaN` values. They are not ignored while using a dict of columns even if the `errors` parameter is set to `'ignore'` .

Here is a toy example:

```
t=pd.DataFrame([[1.01,2],[3.01, 10], [np.NaN,20]])
t.astype({0: int}, errors='ignore')
```

> ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: this looks like a bug! You can go around that by using `fillna(0)` and then apply the `astype()`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the workaround ! Unfortunately I need these NA... Were you able to reproduce it ? I'm using `Python 3.6.7` and `pandas '0.24.2'`

Comment: Very good question!

Comment: @GCa yes I am getting the same with `python 3.7.3` and `pandas 0.23.4`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the new [nullable integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) dtype in pandas 0.24.0+.  You'll first need to convert any floats that aren't exactly equal to integers to be equal to integer values (e.g. rounding, truncating, etc.) before using `astype`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np; import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.24.2'

In [2]: t = pd.DataFrame([[1.01, 2],[3.01, 10], [np.NaN, 20]])

In [3]: t.round().astype('Int64')
Out[3]:
     0   1
0    1   2
1    3  10
2  NaN  20
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
t.astype('int64', copy=False, errors='ignore')
```

---

Will output:

```
    0   1
0   1.01    2
1   3.01    10
2   NaN     20
```

As per the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) this may be a `dtype`.

---

UPDATE:

```
t=pd.DataFrame([[1.01,2],[3.01, 10], [np.NaN,20]],
              columns=['0', '1'])
t.astype({'0': 'int64', '1': 'int64'}, errors='ignore')
```

I tried also to add column names to you dataset, but in failure. May be some notation quirks, a bug or a problem with in place copy.

Comment: OK, even when I set the column names, it did not work. Sorry. @GCa

Comment: No need to be sorry :-). thank you for your help: it might be a bug as @VnC [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56169473/dataframe-astype-errors-parameter/56170093?noredirect=1#comment98965919_56169473) !

Comment: it's Int64 not int64 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
out = t.fillna(99999).astype(int)
final = out.replace(99999, 'Nan')
```

Output:

```
     0   1
0    1   2
1    3  10
2  Nan  20
```

Comment: As answered to @VnC 0 is an actual value, I need NaN unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I saw your point at first. 99999 is still a value. It won't work (returns a float column), NaN shouldn't be a string, no dict of column used.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
t_new=t.mask(t.notnull(),t.values.astype(int))
```

Comment: returns float and way to slow for big dataframe.